# Daawah to a female by a male

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, dawah

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

It has been a couple of weeks when I try to give daawah to the people around me especially female which are my relative, I now started thinking of maybe what am doing is right or wrong (halal or Haram)

Comment: Didn't understand correctly, why would you want to change their lifes and what ways?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No its not right, because the you are dessiving them where they think that you like them whilst you are just doing that to "change them" and then it is not your responbilty to change them, you may give me guidence and thats it, otherewise you can make duaa for them